# how to use structure member types for hashing?

Tags: data-structures, encoding, lisp, common-lisp, static-typing

I am porting a hashing code for [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) communication, so It needs to hash the data type to send it. Types should be uint8 sint8, uint16, sint16, ... , sint64

```
;; lisp types -- byte := bit
(deftype uint8  () '(UNSIGNED-BYTE 8))
(deftype sint8  () '(SIGNED-BYTE 8))    ;
(deftype uint16 () '(UNSIGNED-BYTE 16))
(deftype sint16 () '(SIGNED-BYTE 16))
(deftype uint32 () '(UNSIGNED-BYTE 32))
(deftype sint32 () '(SIGNED-BYTE 32))
(deftype uint64 () '(UNSIGNED-BYTE 64))
(deftype sint64 () '(SIGNED-BYTE 64))
```

"I am using SBCL"

The data is stored in a structure with types specified

Problems:

- When the data is 0  or 1 it gets type bit which fits in all -fixnum, unsigned-byte, signed-byte- types.
- Types size inference!! for signed and unsigned
- Types use type hierarchy, so I can't have unique types.

I only use types for hashing the structure with (`etypecase`, `subtypep`)

I have read [Xdr-Binding-to-Lisp](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Xdr-Binding-to-Lisp-Antoy-Davidson/1492cfc3b024ebbfaf30007d1512e7c697958640), but I don't understand how they used `case` or `typecase` to differ between uint8 and sint8. [drx on github](https://github.com/fjames86/drx) uses encode_int, encode_array, ...

What I want:

```
(defstruct example
  (x 0           :type lcm:sint32)
  (y "blablabla" :type string)
  (z 1.8d0       :type double-float))
```

quickly hash the structure slots information using (`etypecase`, `subtypep`).

EDIT:

I want to hash lisp-structure `TYPE SLOTS` "string sint8 float array" to read the data correctly when received/sent. If I have a struct. st:

```
(typecase st
    (structure-object (recursive do this))
    (sint8 (do this))
    (string (recursive do this))
    (uint8 ( do this))
...
```

I use typecase to recursively convert type info. ---> integer

The following is the code for structure definition:

```
(defvar *struct-types* (make-array 0
                                   :adjustable t
                                   :fill-pointer 0))

(defmacro deflcmstruct (name options &rest slots)
  "Define a struct"
  (let ((slot-types '()))
    `(progn
       (defstruct (,name (:include lcm-type options))
         ,@(mapcar (lambda (slot)
                     (destructuring-bind (slot-name slot-type &rest slot-args)
                         slot
                       ()
                       (declare (ignore slot-type))
                       `(,slot-name ,@slot-args)))
                   slots))
       ,(vector-push-extend  *struct-types* name)
       ,(vector-push-extend  *struct-types* (make-hash-table))
```

Questions:

- If a lisp structure has a slot with number say: 5 how to make lisp understand 5 type uniquely as sint8/uint8/sin16/uint16, but not fit all these types only one?
- How can I hash data types(custom) using lisp?
- If I have to store the type def. then What are options to do so?? I am think of building a hash-table using `gensym`, but this hash-table would be floating around!!
- How to make data-type structure isolated?or better a better design?
- Examples would be great.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: I think you should define your own struct-defining macro which will also generate a hash function for the struct

Comment: This is what I have done, but I want to see if there's a better than floating hash-table.

Comment: this sentence does not make any sense. Could you please also adjust your question to give an example of what you want have already or what you want to get.

Comment: No. What is lcm-type? What is options? Where do you do any hashing? All I see is a hash table. I don’t understand what you want?

Comment: How is `etypecase` and `subtypep` related to hashing?

Comment: Icm-type used with subtypep to check for errors only.

Comment: No. What is `TYPE SLOTS`?

Comment: string, uint8, sint8, double-float, single float, array, ...

Comment: You’ve not yet told anyone what you want so I picked a few words at random from your question and tried to guess what you meant.

Comment: I used 'typecase' to get slot-type and it works for string,boolean,array and, sturucture, but this method doesn't work for numbers, so I want to know in advance the data type and I have to change my code(not much) to fix that or use other methods to resolve number types in lisp. example: 0 23  213 123 fits for uint8 ,sint8, uint16, ... so I can't use typecase for numbers.

Comment: SO my question was how lisp can resolve that without storing the type field?

Comment: If I can't what would be a good representation for data-types?

Comment: Am I clear now? Thanks for your time.

Comment: No you aren’t clear. What does this question have to do with hashing? I searched the wiki page and rfc and neither mentions “hash”

Comment: @Catch.Me No. please update your question to include: code for some data structure; an explanation of what thing you want in the context of this data structure; code specific to this data structure for what you want (I think this should be code to send/receive this structure); code that computes the “hash” of this data structure; a reference to the where in the spec this hashing is referenced. Please do not include the phrase “Got me?”. This will be my last comment.

Comment: I want to assign types to numbers in lisp without the canonical structure, so 1 or 0 should be interpreted as (unsigned-byte 8) or (signed-byte 8), but not both. I don't include encoding, hashing, send/receive because they aren't the problem. I put them just to give a context of why I want to assign a static type. regards

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an example of how you might do it:

```
(defgeneric generic-hash (object))
(defmethod generic-hash ((x integer))
  (error “GENERIC-HASH does not work on integers as it does not know what size field to put them in.”))
(defun hash-for-type (type)
  ;; could also be done with a hash table
  (case type
    (uint8 'hash-uint8)
    ;; ...
    (otherwise 'generic-hash)))

(defun hash-function-for-struct-definition (var name slots)
  (flet ((access (sym)
           (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name name) "-" (symbol-name sym)) (symbol-package sym))))
    (let ((hashed-slots
             (loop for slot in slots collect
                  (let ((type (etypecase slot (symbol t) (cons (or (getf :type slot) t))))
                        (name (if (consp slot) (car slot) slot)))
                    (list (hash-for-type type) (list (access name var)))))))
      (reduce (lambda (a b) (list 'combine-hash a b)) hashed-slots))))

(defmacro my-defstruct (name &rest slots)
  (let* ((var (gensym)) (hash (hash-function-for-struct-definition var name slots)))
    `(progn
        (defstruct ,name ,@slots)
        (defmethod generic-hash ((,var ,name))
          ,hash))))
```

The trick is that although you can’t tell what type a field is by the value in it, you do get the types at structure definition time and so you can define your own defstruct-like macro which, knowing the types of the fields, can generate suitable methods based on the declared types. A second way to do this would be at runtime by inspecting the class of the object but that would be quite slow in comparison and the compiler probably wouldn’t be able to optimize that at all.